# ¿ingeniería inversa SQL SERVER?

Tags: sql, sql-server

¿Hay alguna manera de obtener los nombres de los procedimientos almacenados y jobs que hacen uso de una tabla partiendo desde la tabla en cuestión en SQL SERVER?

Comment: @Aprendiz no veo como pueda estar basada en opiniones.

Comment: Una es mía y no tiene ninguna opinión.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Existen distintas opciones.

Puedes hacerlo por medio de la interfaz gráfica dando clic derecho en la tabla en el explorador de objetos y seleccionar "Ver Dependencias". Ahí podrás ver los objetos de la base de datos que están siendo usados por la tabla y de cuales objetos depende la tabla.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Otra opción es hacerlo mediante código usando las vistas del sistema.

```
SELECT *
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies 
WHERE referenced_entity_name = 'NombreTabla';
```

Sin embargo, estos métodos no permiten ver los jobs que hacen referencia a la tabla. Para eso podrías usar un Código como el siguiente para ver el código usado por los jobs.

```
SELECT j.name, 
       js.step_id,
       js.step_name,
       js.subsystem,
       js.command
FROM msdb.dbo.sysjobs j
JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps js ON j.job_id = js.job_id
WHERE command LIKE '%NombreTabla%';
```

Ten cuidado con esto puesto que puede tener falsos positivos si el nombre de la tabla puede ser parte de otro nombre dentro del código.

Answer (score 0):

Existe una herramienta llamada `SQL SERVER PROFILER` que te permite realizar una traza en la base de datos de todas las acciones que se realicen ej: ejecutar un sp, trigger o cualquier otra accion que se realice en la BD

[Link de la documentacion sobre PROFILER](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/sql-server-profiler/sql-server-profiler?view=sql-server-ver15)